# cordova-sqlite-storage not working on Xcode 11.3

Tags: sqlite, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, xcode11, sqlstorage

After updating my Xcode 11.3 and iOS 13 devices. the sqlite-storage plugin throws thread issue. Any solution for this?. I've attached issue on Xcode image. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhwea.png)